Weighted input for sentence similarity
I am building a language model for sentence similarity using dot score. Currently, I am using gte-largelanguage model from hugging face.
I was wondering if there is a way to give a weighted input of text. For example, the input sentence
Crickets-insect
Is there a way to give more weightage to insect here so that when compared with huge number of words, it shows more similarity with insects than cricket the sport?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
